# is there any solution for this git problem

Tags: git, github, git-config

```
git :- error : could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin permission denied windows
```

[image]

Comment: `%HOME%`, sweet `%HOME%`…

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, git cannot find your home folder; it seems to think that it's

```
c:\program files\java\jdk-17\bin
```

Normally, any change using `git config --global` affects `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`.

The behaviour that you see would mean that you used `git config --system`. Windows will not allow the listed file to be changed, because you'd need to be a full admin.

BTW: Where is your git installed? It's unlikely that it comes with Java.